# how to control access to url in meteor

Tags: meteor

I wish to control access to specific urls running in my meteor web application. How should I proceed. I searched this [Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/) but to no avail. I am new to meteor, please guide.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor has no builtin routing.

You should checkout https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router or https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-router

Comment: Iron Router is the preferred one.